# Insert 2 values that share the same primary key into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing code to create a table in order to save the calculation process. After the table is created, I wanted to insert 2 rows of data that share all the same values except rid and aid. This is the create table code that I have written:

```
create table McLeanActivityTotal(
    rlname  varchar(20) not null,
    guest#  varchar(4) not null,
    inv#    char(5) not null,
    rdate   date not null,
    rid     char(5) not null,
    aid     varchar(3) not null,
    numberinparty   tinyint not null,
    personprice     decimal(4,2) not null,
    activitytotal   int not null,
    primary key (guest#),
    foreign key (guest#) references guests(guest#),
    foreign key (rid) references reservations(rid)
);
```

```
insert into McLeanActivityTotal(rlname, guest#, inv#, rdate, rid, aid, numberinparty, personprice, activitytotal)
    select rlname, g.guest#, i.inv#, RDate, r.RID, a.AID,NumberInParty, PPP, (NumberInParty*PPP)"activitytotal"
    from INVOICEDETAILS id
    join INVOICE i on id.INV#=i.INV#
    join RESERVATIONS r on r.RID=id.RID
    join GUESTS g on g.Guest#=r.Guest#
    join ACTIVITIES a on a.AID=r.AID
    where year(RDate)=2019 and id.INV#=20065 and r.RID='16042'

insert into McLeanActivityTotal(rlname, guest#, inv#, rdate, rid, aid, numberinparty, personprice, activitytotal)
    select rlname, g.guest#, i.inv#, RDate, r.RID, a.AID,NumberInParty, PPP, (NumberInParty*PPP)"activitytotal"
    from INVOICEDETAILS id
    join INVOICE i on id.INV#=i.INV#
    join RESERVATIONS r on r.RID=id.RID
    join GUESTS g on g.Guest#=r.Guest#
    join ACTIVITIES a on a.AID=r.AID
    where year(RDate)=2019 and id.INV#=20065 and r.RID='16006'
```

After running this I get this error messages:

> (1 row affected)

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 140
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__McLeanAc__3D3F26AC02F7B9D0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.McLeanActivityTotal'. The duplicate key value is (G5).

I know that only the first data that has rid=10642 was inserted not the other. How can I insert both of them into this table?

Comment: A primary key is by definition also a unique key i.e. you cannot insert duplicates. The real question here is, why have you defined your foreign key column (guest#) as your primary key? Normally, unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, you would declare your primary key as being your id column, and your id column as being `int identity`. You may wish to refresh your knowledge with a tutorial or two. Having any keys, primary or foreign as varchar(x) is not a best practice. Normally one uses an int, sometimes one uses a uniqueidentifier (but thats an advanced case).

Comment: @DaleK yes I am pretty much a newbie in programming&sql. I was trying to populate a new table that stores data of the process of fixing wrong data that was challenged by a customer. So I tried to create a table that stores the guest data and the designated columns needed and then insert the guest data afterwards. When creating the new table, I just tried to match the data types of the attributes from their original tables. And

Comment: @DaleKI was given example how it should print out so I ordered the attributes in the same way starting with "rlname" but I thought that it is not a good idea to assign it as a primary key so I assigned guest# as the primary key, since it is a primary key in the table where it originally came from. My objective is to insert 2 data rows of 1 guest from original database, and as you can see, I find it so hard.

Comment: Yeah, but your original table with `guest#` as its primary key will not have duplicate rows. Just create a regular id column on your new table e.g. `id int identity(1,1)` and use that as your primary key. But I would really suggest doing some reading, because getting people to answer questions like this won't give the broad understanding you need to work databases.

Comment: @DaleK so I just changed the assigned primary key to rid which is unique within the restricted result and it worked (for now). Although I couldn't really imagine what kind of problems this code structure might face in the future...

Comment: Well, you seem to be storing integer values in `rid` and it's defined as a `char(5)` data type. What do you think will happen after `rid` reaches `99999`? Don't just make this `char(6)` or `char(10)` to work around it - if it's actually an integer value make it `int` or `bigint`.

Comment: Seriously just create a new, int PK, you really want to avoid it having any meaning or relationship.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dale K mentioned it's better to have an Identity column as primary key if you don't have reason to do other wise. Changing primary key from guest# to rid might solve your problem for now. But you need to be sure that there is no possible way for `rid` to be duplicated in future.

And if you are storing number in rid please change this column from char(5) to integer. And if only `aid` and `rid` columns have duplicate values between same kind of rows then I would suggest you to introduce ID column in this table as primary key and create a new table with ID, rid and aid column. SO that, McLeanActivityTotal will have one row against which the new table will have two rows. You can easily join them to get your final result.